# How to get the content of a text file using command FOR on a batch file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have a text file where the contents have a lot of NUL or spaces between data:

[nul][nul][nul][nul]Name [nul][nul][nul][nul][nul][nul]surname

The data inside of the text file is always different.

I have searched and tested many similar questions using for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do echo %%a and similar commands, but i always get empty results.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: NUL is going to be problematic using only standard batch processing. See here for information on how you may approach it https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=7407#p7407

Comment: We would need more information about the specifics of the file itself. It is clearly not a standard ANSI plain text file. Unless we can reproduce your specific issue, we will struggle to provide focused solutions, and would have to resort to best guesses. As a technical site, best guesses should be avoided. Perhaps you could upload a copy of your file for interested parties to download and assess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly have a text file with, for example, the following content:

[External image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pphfn.jpg)

And you just want to omit the `NUL` characters as part of a normal `For /F` loop file read, then you could ask [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) for help from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
 '%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ^
 -Nologo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content 'sourcefile.txt')" ^
 " -replace '\x00',''"') Do @Echo(%%G
@Pause
```

I have split that long line up into multiple for easier reading, but you could also have it as a single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@(For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Nologo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content 'sourcefile.txt') -replace '\x00',''"') Do @Echo(%%G) & Pause
```

And to do it in simple terms directly from the Command Prompt [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```batch-file
For /F "Delims=" %G In ('powershell -NoP "(GC 'sourcefile.txt') -replace '\x00',''"') Do @Echo(%G
```

---

**[Edit /]**

If you wanted to add a single com**m**a, between those two specific words in the exact example you provided, and which I used in my linked image above, then yes, it would be possible.

For example you could do it within the PowerShell part, by changing:

`-replace '\x00',''` to `-replace ' ',', ' -replace '\x00',''`

Or, you could do it by changing the `For` loop option:

`"Delims="` to `"Tokens=1*"`

and then change either:

`@Echo(%%G`, or `@Echo(%G`

to:

`@Echo(%%G, %%H` or `@Echo(%G, %H` respectively.

Comment: That's Brilliant! Thank you. Don't want to push my luck, but if i wanted to add a single coma between the different words, will it be possible?

Comment: that's excellent. Thank you. I have voted for your answer, but because my reputation is only 1, the vote does not appear publicly.